# $(x_1, y_1) = \infty \implies x = -y$ with elliptic curve of a cubic equation

Tags: conic-sections, elliptic-curves

In Lawrence Washington's book on Elliptic Curves section 2.5.2 on Cubic Equations, starting from $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 0$ such that $xyz \neq 0$, he derives
$$\frac{x}{z} = u + v, \qquad \frac{y}{z} = u - v$$
$$(u + v)^3 + 6uv^2 + 1 = 0 \implies 6(v/u)^2 = -(1/u)^3 - 2$$
Let
$$x_1 = \frac{-6}{u} = -12 \frac{z}{x + y}, \qquad y_1 = \frac{36v}{u} = 36 \frac{x - y}{x + y}$$
Then
$$y_1^2 = x_1^3 - 432$$
So far so good. But then he states $(x_1, y_1) = \infty$ is a solution, and that $(x_1, y_1) = \infty$ corresponds to $x = -y \implies z = 0$.

How did he get from $(x_1, y_1) = \infty \implies x = -y$? I can see how if we used projective coordinates, then the identity value would mean $z = 0$, but how did he first get $x = -y$? Where does this derivation come from?

Answer (score 0):

Washington avoids projective coordinates.

In projective space, all affine solutions have the form $(x,y,1)$ with last coordinate 1, while the solutions at infinity are of shape $(x,y,0)$ with $x\ne 0\ne y$.
Here $(x,-x,0)$ is a solution at infinity.

Comment: Thanks, but how did Washington get this solution without resorting to projective coordinates as you have done?

Comment: Sorry but not really my question as in my lecture I use projective space.

Comment: How did Washington get his answer without using projective coordinates? And still if $(x_1, y_1) = \infty$ and $(x_1, -x_1)$ is a solution as you've specified, then $y_1 = -x_1 \implies y - x = \frac{z}{3}$...

Comment: So how did he get the solution without using projective coordinates?

Comment: I'm not following his notes.